# My insertion is not able to be actualized through PreparedStatement

Tags: java, database

Once i execute the following code, realize that insertion can't be done. i can see row value is 1 after executing of prepstmt.executeUpdate() but insertion record is not listed in database. i also used resultset to verify if concerned record is created but on that line i'm facing with null pointer exception. what might be the reason ? any idea ?

```
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
       Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.31.60.83:1521:TBCEBTRL", "TESTUSER","TESTUSER");
       String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO PROVISIONING_MGNT.MERNIS_CUSTOMER_INFO (TC_ID,MOTHER_TC_ID,FATHER_TC_ID, BIRTHPLACE_CODE,SPOUSE_TC_ID, NAME, SURNAME, SEX, FATHER_NAME, MOTHER_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH_YEAR, DATE_OF_BIRTH_MONTH, DATE_OF_BIRTH_DAY, PLACE_OF_BIRTH, STATUS, MARITAL_STATUS,RELIGION,DATE_OF_DEATH_YEAR,DATE_OF_DEATH_MONTH,DATE_OF_DEATH_DAY, PROVINCE_CODE, PROVINCE_NAME, COUNTY_CODE, COUNTY_NAME, VOLUME_CODE, VOLUME_NAME, FAMILY_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, PERSON_SEQUENCE_NUMBER,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_DESCRIPTION,CREATION_TIME,DOCUMENT_NO) "
                          + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
       PreparedStatement prepstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
       //Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
       Random r = new Random();
       int number = 1000000000 + (int)(r.nextDouble() * 999999999);
       ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
       long x = random.nextLong(10_000_000_000L, 100_000_000_000L);
       System.out.println(random.nextLong(10_000_000_000L, 100_000_000_000L));
       prepstmt.setLong(1, x);
       prepstmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.NULL );
       prepstmt.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.NULL );
       prepstmt.setInt(4, 1542);
       prepstmt.setNull(5, java.sql.Types.NULL );
       prepstmt.setString(6, "TEST");
       prepstmt.setString(7, "TEST");
       prepstmt.setString(8, "Male");
       prepstmt.setString(9, "Father");
       prepstmt.setString(10, "Mother");
       prepstmt.setInt(11,1968);
       prepstmt.setInt(12,10);
       prepstmt.setInt(13,10);
       prepstmt.setString(14,"ADANA");
       prepstmt.setString(15,"Open");
       prepstmt.setString(16,"Single");
       prepstmt.setNull(17, java.sql.Types.NULL );
       prepstmt.setNull(18, java.sql.Types.NULL );
       prepstmt.setNull(19, java.sql.Types.NULL );
       prepstmt.setNull(20, java.sql.Types.NULL );
       prepstmt.setInt(21,1);
       prepstmt.setString(22,"ADANA");
       prepstmt.setInt(23,1101);
       prepstmt.setString(24,"TEST");
       prepstmt.setInt(25,1);
       prepstmt.setString(26,"MERKEZ");
       prepstmt.setInt(27,39);
       prepstmt.setInt(28,2);
       prepstmt.setNull(29, java.sql.Types.NULL );
       prepstmt.setNull(30, java.sql.Types.NULL );
       prepstmt.setNull(31, java.sql.Types.NULL );
       prepstmt.setInt(32,number);
       int row = prepstmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(number);
        System.out.println(row);
       ResultSet rs = prepstmt.getResultSet();
       rs.next();
         String name = rs.getString("NAME");
         System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I think `getResultSet()` always returns `null` for update statements. You would need to write another statement with a select.

Comment: It should be insertion. getResultSet() is just verification to understand that i made the insertion or not. the problem is in insertion but where exactly it is, i dont know.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code tbh. But your method of verification probably won't ever work as insert doesn't return any results.